# Routing URL is not working as previous in angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, angular7, query-string

Routing module Path configuration

```
{ path: 'invite/:token', component: PreAuthComponent },
```

Previously we were using

```
localhost:4200/#/invite/?key=12345
```

but after update to angular 7 it's not taking both /? combine and not able to navigate. How to achieve this with same configuration mentioned above.

currently working URL's with different configuration

```
{ path: 'invite/:token', component: PreAuthComponent }

localhost:4200/#/invite/12345
```

or

```
{ path: 'invite', component: PreAuthComponent }

localhost:4200/#/invite?key=12345
```

Comment: Do you need both the key & the token?

Comment: @TusharWalzade Yes I need both in URL like localhost:4200/#/invite/?key=1234

Answer (score 2):

According to [Locationstrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles), you may update the `LocationStrategy` by set `useHash: true` in `RouterModule.forRoot()` method as following.

```ts
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  // .../#/crisis-center/
```

By the way, the route parameter ("/feature/:id") and query parameter ("feature?key=value") is very different in Angular. route parameter can be used for routing and processed by component. Usually, query parameter is only processed in NgComponent.

Comment: LocationStrategy already been configured in project, but it won't help to achieve what URL pattern I want. I need both **/?** in URL like localhost:4200/#/invite **/?** key=1234

Comment: So, 2 question here. 1) why `HashLocationStrategy` does not work? I may need your router configuration file for investigation. 2) how to route according to query parameter? As I know, router cannot navigate based on query parameter. So, you need work around. It depends on your design of component. e.g. if `invite` component is same component of `invite\12345`, or `invite\12345` is child component of `invite`. you can do this in the code of `invite` component. if not, do it in CanActivate guard of `invite` component.